# Как регулярным выражением достать нужную информацию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть несколько строк в таких форматах:

`"some text ({asdf-13f-fasdf})"` и `"some text [new info {assf-13f-fdasdf}]"`

Я получаю данные в таком виде `({asdf-13f-fasdf})`, а мне нужно именно содержимое, а не скобки.

Пример: `asdf-13f-fasdf`

Код:

```
import re

text = "some text ({asdf-13f-fasdf})"

test = re.search('some text (\(.*?)\)', text)
print(test.group(1))
```

Результат: ({asdf-13f-fasdf}

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Я получаю данные в таком виде ({asdf-13f-fasdf}), а мне нужно именно
> содержимое, а не скобки.

Чтобы фигурные скобки не захватывало, нужно добавить круглые скобки

Попробуйте:

```
import re

text = """
some text ({asdf-13f-fasdf})
и
some text [new info {DEAD-13f-fdasdf}]
"""

print(re.findall(r'{(.+?)}', text))
# ['asdf-13f-fasdf', 'DEAD-13f-fdasdf']

m = re.search('{(.+?)}', text)
print(m.group(1))
# asdf-13f-fasdf
```

---

**UPD.**

Обработка текстового файла построчно:

```
with open("log.txt", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        m = re.search('{(.+?)}', line)
        print(m.group(1))
```

Если уже есть строка с кучей строк, то используйте у нее метод `splitlines`:

```
with open("log.txt", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read()
    for line in text.splitlines():
        ...
```

Comment: Да, это сработало, но у меня немного другой тип. Сейчас прикеплю к вопросу свой код

Comment: @Farid, читайте файл построчно и к каждой строке вызывайте регулярку. Если данные в одном значение, то вызывайте `search` и `group`. Обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

А срез нельзя сделать?

```
import re

text = "some text ({asdf-13f-fasdf})"

test = re.search('some text (\(.*?)\)', text)
print(test.group(1)[2:-2]) # В чем проблема сделать просто срез или я что не понял в вопросе
```

Comment: Просто у меня очень большой текстовый файл и в каждой строке очень много слов, к примеру: `Login attempt from user IES\A.Skryabin from 10.54.215.49 (OtClient, NTLM) session 30457 [replacing session {499D7853-5546-4017-9831-ED3A40D38B41}] lang=ru,443` . И я отсюда достаю необходимые мне данные, по типу user, session id и в том числе данные которые в скобках. Я это все сделал, но часть со скобками мне выводится со скобками и я их хочу удалить